I need path of file to use this npm packages, but i have only Arraybuffer of file
I want to use node-qpdf2 in my project. but the problem is that need of file path, but i have only Arraybuffer/buffer/remoteUrl of the file. so how use this packages.
const data = await fetch(`https://api.telegram.org/file/mytoken/${img.file_path}`)
    const buff = await data.arrayBuffer()
    const buf = Buffer.from(buff) // CONVERT TO BUFFER FROM BUFFER ARRAY
    

I have this  buffer and want to use this in below code.
import { encrypt } from "node-qpdf2";

const pdf = {
  input: "./test/example.pdf",
  output: "/tmp/encrypted.pdf",
  password: "1234",
}

await encrypt(pdf);

how i can do this or any other approach to achieve this
